# Can you add more than 4 Gmail priority inbox sections?

Tags: gmail, priority-inbox

I'm interested in setting up my priority inbox with 5-6 sections, but Gmail settings limit you to 4. I've found [**this alleged settings hack**](http://thenextweb.com/lifehacks/2014/07/14/3-gmail-tricks-can-save-hours-every-week/) to add additional priority inbox sections; however, I cannot get this to work.

> If you inspect “Remove Section,” and change the corresponding act=”z” snippet to act=”n” (highlighted in the image below) and then click “Remove Section,” this will add another new section!
>
> There doesn’t seem to be a cap on the number of sections you can
>   create through this technique, and these changes will persist for
>   future browser sessions just like the Unread trick.

[image]

I'm not sure if this still works, or if the snippet needs to be updated based on some  Gmail updates.

Answer (score 1):

This is feature is not currently available. You can suggest new features (and vote for the most common suggestions) here:  http://mail.google.com/support/bin/request.py?contact_type=suggest  (perhaps using the "I have another idea" option at the bottom)

Source: https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/gmail/fbzQMggCzzw